# JQuery Ajax Autocomplete Not Displaying Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that load Jquery autocomplete, I got the result, but it does not shows up (blank with border). Just like this image:
[image: Here's my UI for fecth autocomplete]

Here's my JQuery Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // Customer
            $('input[name=\'customer\']').autocomplete({
                delay: 500,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'getCustomer.php?filter_name=' + encodeURIComponent(request.term),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (json) {
                            response($.map(json, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.c_name,
                                    value: item.c_id
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $('input[name=\'customer\']').val(ui.item.label);
                    $('input[name=\'customer_id\']').val(ui.item.value);
                    return false;
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
</script>
```

And here's AJAX result:
[image: Ajax Result]

Anyone here have same problem before? I'm using Admin LTE template by the way. And still wondering what's wrong with my code. I have tried import other `Jquery-min-js` but still not working. Still displayed like that (blank bordered). FYI: there's no error at console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the AJAX response you've shown (as an image) is the actual response from the server, before your `$.map()` has modified it.

Your `$.map()` function iterates over that `json` response from the server, and it tries to use the `c_name` and `c_id` property names in each element.  But the `json` from the server does not include those property names - it has `customer_id` and `name`.

So the `$.map()` creates a bunch of empty elements, and passes them on to autocomplete.  Autocomplete then has a set of elements to display, but without any labels, which is why you see the dropdown with empty horizontal lines, rather than just nothing at all, which is what you'd see when there's no response/match at all.

You simply need to use the same property names you have in your AJAX:

```
response($.map(json, function (item) {
    return {
        label: item.name,
        value: item.customer_id
    }
}));
```